# Adding reusable view to a tableViewCell dynamically

Tags: swift3, xcode8, ios10

Need help in designing a specific screen for ios (iPad application).

How to add two or more views/cells with each view having an image and few labels to a tableView Cell dynamically, with each views adjacent to each other in a row?
Provided, in the design it has Number of views in a section, and it would be dynamic, so the row height is also dynamic.

Thanks in advance!